# International weather API (PHP)

Tags: php, api, weather

I'm looking for the best (free/cheap) international weather PHP API out there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look in this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507441/best-weather-apis

the chosen answer give this   :

•The National Weather Service has a SOAP Web service.

•Yahoo has a weather RSS feed.

•Animaonline is a weather API powered by Google. There are code samples and tutorial links on the project page, but I found another tutorial here.

Comment: As the link in that answer has been deleted I thought I would add reference to another API which offers free access [World Weather Online](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/api/docs/local-city-town-weather-api.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to do with the data?

If you just want to display it, look for a weather site with an RSS feed. Then you can easily request it, cache it on your server and parse it.

For requesting, use cURL or `file_get_contents()` (if your `php.ini` allows it).

For caching, just check `filemtime()` and make a comparison.

To parse it, use SimpleXML.

Answer (score 2):

[Yahoo Weather](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) or [Google Weather](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=New%20York) are both fast and free. I've used Google the most, you can use both city name or latitude/longitude to collect data.

Worth noting is that Google doesn't really provide an API and is undocumented, so no one knows the future of it.

Comment: Thanks! But the Yahoo Weather API. Is it possible to make a search engine for it? I see you need to use a unique WOEID in the URL like this; http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=locatio to get the right location. This works great if all users on my site only have one Weather feed. But is it possible to make a search engine (with PHP) so that the users can costumize the location?

Answer (score 0):

Both weathernation and feedsyndicate.com both offer a commercial api

Weathernation.com isn't very inexpensive..  feedsyndicate can be but you need to ask for a deal.