# How to use dynamic weather forecast and a database of the same on my website?

Tags: php

I have a website on which I want weather forecast to be displayed but in a very specific manner. Suppose, a visitor visits my website and searches for "Mumbai" in my weather forecast text box. Then, he would get the weather forecast for "Mumbai" for the next few days. In the same manner it should happen for other cities too.

Could anyone over here help me out on this?

Comment: and what role does the database have in this scenario? you want to store the forecasts there? or some city-to-city relationships? for the other portion you'll just need to choose an API that you like (such as): http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/04/15/5-weather-apis-from-weatherbug-to-weather-channel/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498399/international-weather-api-php

Comment: Actually I also need to SMS the weather forecast of the particular city in which the member resides!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a widget ...

```
        <iframe marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="wxButtonFrame" id="wxButtonFrame" height="110" src="http://btn.weather.ca/weatherbuttons/template5.php?placeCode=INXX0026&category0=Cities&containerWidth=150&btnNo=&backgroundColor=blue&multipleCity=0&citySearch=1&celsiusF=C" align="top" frameborder="0" width="150" scrolling="no" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

c/o http://www.theweathernetwork.com/

Maybe you want to look at using a weather webservice:

- [Weather web service for Europe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108025/weather-web-service-for-europe)
- http://www.deeptraining.com/webservices/weather.asmx

As you have not really articulated how you want a database integrated with this question ... this is the best i have for you!

1. Get the data
2. Display the data

You really don't need to store the data unless you have millions of requests ... at which point, caching the results is a good idea...